# How to set a boolean type property in objective C class

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, properties, boolean

How to use a boolean property in objective C class, i did it like:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) BOOL *locationUseBool;
```

but it gives error that:

> Property with 'copy' attribute must be of object type.

what is the correct way of declaring?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can declare this way also.

```
@property (assign) BOOL locationUseBool;
```

Basically, if you say nonatomic, and you generate the accessors using @synthesize, then if multiple threads try to change/read the property at once, badness can happen. You can get partially-written values or over-released/retained objects

In a multi-threaded program, an atomic operation cannot be interrupted partially through, whereas nonatomic operations can.

Answer (score 25):

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL locationUseBool;
```

No asterisk, no copy, no retain.

Comment: Or you can omit the second parameter altogether (defaulting to assign).

Comment: Also consider using the official C99 `bool` type.  It has better behaviour when casting etc.

Comment: @JeremyP when casting to what? `BOOL` is recommended by everything I've ever read on Obj-C. What am I missing?

Comment: @Yar: `BOOL` is just a typedef for `char`.  `bool` is a proper boolean type that is logically 1 bit wide.  In C, any number of integer type that is not 0 is meant to evaluate to true.  However  casting any non zero integer whose lower 8 bits happen to be zero to `BOOL` will result in a BOOL variable that is false.  `(BOOL)0x1000` is false but `(bool) 0x1000` is true.

Comment: @JeremyP I'm shocked! http://pastie.org/3438141 So, um, should I be using `bool` for everything everywhere, like properties, etc.? Admittedly, I'm not assigning `ints` to BOOLs much, but what's the cost-benefit?

Comment: @Yar: I use standard C99 types everywhere except where a Foundation or Cocoa API specifies one of the Foundation types.  And in respect of booleans, I always do something like `(x ? YES : NO)` rather than rely on the cast.

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433121/implications-of-int-values-not-fitting-bool-or-bool-for-objective-c where I expand this into a full thinger... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This one worked for me.

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL locationUseBool;
```

There is not asterisk * symbol in property declaration. Also, use of 'assign' is optional.