# Implications of int values not “fitting” – bool or BOOL for Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, primitive

In the comments here -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/9393138/8047 -- I discovered that `BOOL` has some unexpected behavior when setting its value from an `int` value. Mostly, if the value is set to `0x1000` it gets evaluated as `FALSE` (surprisingly).

```
NSLog(@"All zero? %d %d", (BOOL)0, (bool)0);
NSLog(@"All one? %d %d %d", (BOOL)4095, (BOOL)4096, (BOOL)4097); // 4096=0x1000 or 8-bits
NSLog(@"All one? %d %d %d", (bool)4095, (bool)4096, (bool)4097);

Produces:
All zero? 0 0
All one? -1 0 1
All one? 1 1 1
```

I think this is odd, but then again, I don't cast from `int` to `BOOL` much anyway. However:

1. Does this imply that `bool` be preferred to `BOOL`? Why or why not?
2. Is it okay to use

`if (thatBool) {`

or should one prefer

`if (thatBool ? YES : NO) {`

And why?

**Note:** This is a more specific version of this question of this -- [Objective-C : BOOL vs bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541289/objective-c-bool-vs-bool) -- but I think it adds to it and is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that `(BOOL)4096` being evaluated to `0` is a simple arithmetic overflow, just as `(BOOL)256`, since `BOOL` is an `unsigned char`. And I think that the `!!` casting trick ("double negation") works fine:

```
NSLog(@"%i", (BOOL)256); // 0
NSLog(@"%i", !!256); // 1
```

That means I’d use `BOOL` to keep the standard Cocoa coding style and simply watch for dangerous type casts. The `thatBool ? YES : NO` expression hurts my eyes, why would you want to do that? :)

Comment: Any link on the `!!` casting trick? These things are a bit hard to search on :)

Comment: It’s a simple [double negation](http://www.google.com/search?q=c+double+negation), that should be easier to search for.

Comment: Thanks @zoul, yes that's easy enough. I think 'watch for dangerous type casts' is right.

Answer (score 2):

1) `bool` is the C++ type, `BOOL` is the Objective-C one.
Casting from `int` to `BOOL` doesn't work properly because `YES` is just `(BOOL)1` = `(signed char)1` (= 0x001) and that isn't equal to `(signed char)4` (= 0x100), for example.

2) Both will work, the second might be unreadable to somebody with little experience in programming. I prefer the good old c-style safe condition check with the constant on the left to prevent accidental omission of one of the equal signs.

```
if (YES == isEnabled) {

}
```

Comment: Just adding that "if (thatBool ? YES : NO) {" is useless, is just an if inside an if (ifception!), it's the same thing.

Comment: I like the Yoda if style, I always imagine that the programmer really talks like this and its just hilarious :)

Comment: And it's very practical, actually :-D

Comment: I find the reversed operand order for `==` disturbing :) And above all I don’t think it’s needed anymore, since modern compilers will warn you about the `if (foo = YES)` assignment.

Comment: True about compiler warning, but 'old habits...' :-)

Comment: what's the advantage of `YES == isEnabled` when `thing` is the same. We do it in PHP, Ruby, and everywhere else: `if (isEnabled) {`... what's the problem? Just curious...

Comment: I prefer to have the values in conditionals laid out in front of me to minimize the guesswork.

Comment: `bool` in this case [is from C99](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767923/c99-boolean-data-type), not C++.

Answer (score 0):

When using an int, you can always be explicit when setting a BOOL by checking if the int is equal to a particular value, e.g.

```
BOOL yesNo = ((int)4096 > 0);
BOOL enableButton = (someInt >= 16);
```

In other words, don't pass the int to the BOOL directly; turn it into a true/false statement.